# Undefined is not a constructor trying to create new instance of one class inside another

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an error `'undefined' is not a constructor` on the following code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can I not use a self invoked function inside a class like that? Or can I not create a new instance of another class like this?

```
function ClassOne() {
    this.foo = 'bar';

    (function() {
        var classTwo = new ClassTwo();
    }());
};

function ClassTwo() {
    this.someVar = 'testing';
};

var ClassOne = new ClassOne();
```

Comment: `var ClassOne = new ClassOne();` You shouldn't name your var `ClassOne` since `ClassOne` is already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var ClassOne = new ClassOne();
```

You're declaring a variable `ClassOne` (initially `undefined`) which hides the previously defined function `ClassOne`.  Try this:

```
var classOne = new ClassOne();
```